# Bash - Set a default prompt

Tags: terminal, osx-lion, bash

I've set a bash prompt like this:

```
PS1='\W\[\e[31m\]$(git branch &>/dev/null; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then \
  echo " $(git branch | grep '^*' |sed s/\*\ //)"; fi)'
```

I want to make it default in order not to enter it every time I open the terminal. 
(I'm using OSX lion / Terminal Version 2.2.1)

---

**Solution:** I put the PS1=... line in ~/.bash_profile as Hai Vu suggested.

Thank you all for your answers

Comment: you mean "bash prompt"? add the command to your `.bashrc` file. Instead of doing git yourself in prompt see [this script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash)

Comment: @Fredrik: this would be better fitted as an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't worked for me. Thank you

Comment: The `.bashrc` may not have been sourced by your `.bash_profile` or your looking in the wrong directory. Add that line to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: new user tip: if you find some answer helpful, you may want to upvote it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `PS1=...` line in `~/.bash_profile` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In general, look also for /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc, ~/.sh_profile, or ~/.profile ( usually for root it's .profile, and for non-root .bash_profile ), etc. In various versions of bash and host platforms, successful hit may vary :) Theoretically, bashrc and bash_profile (shrc, sh_profile) are for different purpose, rc file for shell configuration, and profile for various settings not related to shell itself, they're processed in fixed order, including system-wide and per-user configuration.

And I'm not sure, if executing an external command like "git" and piping to sed, grep and more is wise to use with prompt setup.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I know nothing about OSX...

As I stated in my comment, your `~/.bashrc` file is the place to put the command.

Depending on how the the shell is invoked you might need to add the following lines to
the file `~/.bash_login`

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_login ]; then
    . .bashrc
fi
```

And again, don't do the sed-thingie yourself to get the git-branch name into your prompt.
USe the amazing bash-script from [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash).

BTW, this is how my prompt looks like (using the script above):

```
PS1='\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h\[\e[31m\] $(__git_ps1 "%s") \[\e[0m\]\[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ '
```